# Drawing a 3D decision boundary of logistic regression

Tags: r, plot, 3d, logistic-regression, boundary

I have fitted a logistic regression model that takes 3 variables into account. I would like to make a 3D plot of the datapoints and draw the decision boundary (which I suppose would be a plane here).

I found an online example that applies to the case (so that you can load the data directly)

```
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mylogit <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
```

I was thinking of using the 3Dscatterplot package, but I am not sure what equation I should write to draw the boundary. Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decision boundary will be a 3-d plane, which you could plot with any 3-d plotting package in R. I'll use `persp` by defining an x-y grid and then calculating the corresponding z value with the `outer` function:

```
# Use iris dataset for example logistic regression
data(iris)
iris$long <- as.numeric(iris$Sepal.Length > 6)
mod <- glm(long~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=iris, family="binomial")

# Plot 50% decision boundary; another cutoff can be achieved by changing the intercept term
x <- seq(2, 5, by=.1)
y <- seq(1, 7, by=.1)
z <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) (-coef(mod)[1] - coef(mod)[2]*x - coef(mod)[3]*y) /
       coef(mod)[4])
persp(x, y, z, col="lightblue")
```

[image]